# How to draw tail end for container in Flutter using Custom painter

Tags: flutter, canvas, chat, custom-painting

I have a chat screen which have the chatItem box with tail end like this

Need to have that tail end in receiver side and sender side as well as
I am currently using custom painter to this. And couldn't able to figure this out.

[image]

```
`class CustomChatBubble extends CustomPainter {CustomChatBubble({this.color, @required this.isOwn});
final Color color;
final bool isOwn;

@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
final paint = Paint()..color = color ?? Colors.blue;

Path paintBubbleTail() {
  Path path;
  if (!isOwn) {
    path = Path()
      ..moveTo(0, size.height)
      ..relativeMoveTo(0,5)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(10, size.height , 0, size.height - 5);
  }
  if (isOwn) {
    path = Path()
      ..moveTo(0, size.height)
      ..relativeMoveTo(0,5)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(10, size.height , 0, size.height - 5);
  }
  return path;
}

final RRect bubbleBody = RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
    Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height), Radius.circular(16));
final Path bubbleTail = paintBubbleTail();

canvas.drawRRect(bubbleBody, paint);
canvas.drawPath(bubbleTail, paint);
}

@override
bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
// TODO: implement shouldRepaint
return true;
}
}`
```

This is the class I used to do
isOwn is for toggle between sender and receiver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the path for your case:

```
    
class CustomChatBubble extends CustomPainter {
  CustomChatBubble({this.color, @required this.isOwn});
  final Color color;
  final bool isOwn;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = color ?? Colors.blue
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    Path path;
    double triangleHeight = 10.0;
    double triangleWidth = 10.0;
    double roundedBorder = 5.0;

    Path drawBubbleBody() {
      if (!isOwn) {
        path = Path()
          ..lineTo(0, size.height)
          ..lineTo(triangleWidth, size.height - triangleHeight)
          ..lineTo(size.width - roundedBorder, size.height - triangleHeight)
          ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width, size.height - triangleHeight,
              size.width, size.height - triangleHeight - roundedBorder)
          ..lineTo(size.width, roundedBorder)
          ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width, 0, size.width - roundedBorder, 0);
        path.close();
      }
      if (isOwn) {
        path = Path()
          ..moveTo(size.width - roundedBorder, 0)
          ..lineTo(roundedBorder, 0)
          ..quadraticBezierTo(0, 0, 0, roundedBorder)
          ..lineTo(0, size.height - triangleHeight - roundedBorder)
          ..quadraticBezierTo(0, size.height - triangleHeight, roundedBorder,
              size.height - triangleHeight)
          ..lineTo(size.width - triangleWidth, size.height - triangleHeight)
          ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
          ..lineTo(size.width, roundedBorder)
          ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width, 0, size.width - roundedBorder, 0);
      }
      return path;
    }

    canvas.drawPath(drawBubbleBody(), paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
// TODO: implement shouldRepaint
    return true;
  }
}
```

In case you want to reproduce:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Material App Bar'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              CustomPaint(
                painter: CustomChatBubble(isOwn: true, color: Colors.grey),
                child: Container(
                  width: 200,
                  height: 50,
                ),
              ),
              CustomPaint(
                painter: CustomChatBubble(isOwn: false, color: Colors.orange),
                child: Container(
                  width: 200,
                  height: 50,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Result :
[image]

Comment: Of course. Path is relative and will adapt to your sizes, only thing you will have to take care is three variables inside - two triangle dimensions and one for rounded corner size.

Comment: Great. Can you share me how you did it?

Comment: To tell the truth with some experience you will make all path in mind, so did I.

Answer (score 0):

How about you use this package?
There are many chat bubble widget in that package.
[flutter_chat_bubble](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_chat_bubble)

Comment: No MediaQuery widget ancestor found.Getting error like this